# Docker volume mapping not working (Linux containers)

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-volume

Docker 17.09.0-ce-win33 (13620)

Running the command:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/api -p 6000:5000 microsoft/dotnet
```

I should get the content of the current folder in the linux `/api` folder.
For some reason the mapping folder was created, yet there is not content...

```
cd api
ls -a
```

Shows an empty list...

Switching to Windows containers and running

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:c:\API -p 6000:5000 microsoft/dotnet
```

Also gives me an empty folder...

Ran Powershell as Administrator to no avail..   any thoughts?

Comment: Have you given docker rights to that drive?

Comment: Yes, it has rights to use it.

Comment: I think it was BitLocker ... my d:\ -drive is locked on startup, maybe that messes with the access afterward.  After removing BitLocker on the drive the files started to show up....